# No Longer Able to Build To Remote Machine on Hololens - "Developer Mode Not Enabled" (But it is)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, visual-studio-2017, hololens

I have been working on a Hololens project using Unity3D since Fall last year. Up to now, we have had no issues building to the device. We have been following the standard procedures for building - build the solution to UWP with the Hololens as the target device, open solution in Visual Studio (2017), x86, building Remote Machine through the network, etc.

Our project has worked fine up until this week, but this week, we were suddenly locked out of the device and had to sign back in (around the time the Hololens 2 was announced and the Hololens 2 emulator was released). From this point on, we have been unable to deploy our project through the built solution to the remote machine (the Hololens). It's worth noting that our project still works fine in the editor.

The error we are given is: "Error DEP0100: Please ensure that target device has developer mode enabled. Could not obtain a developer license on [IPv4 Address] due to error 80004005."

Of course, the device has developer mode enabled and has had it enabled for 7 months, but I double-checked. I also tried disabling and re-enabling developer mode. I also restarted the device several times, and rebuilt and attempted to re-deploy the build from several different windows machines on several different networks (home and university Wi-Fi). Each machine and location gives the same error. I updated the Hololens to the most recent update hoping that would solve it, but no dice.

Others with the same issue have said they solved it through factory resetting the device, but this would be an absolute last resort for us. This project is for a year-long capstone class and we're worried resetting it is a point of no return that may render our project or the device unusable. The device also does not belong to us, and was lent to us by a faculty member, so we would not want to factory reset their property.

Are there any other solutions I might try?

Comment: Did you try to deploy a new empty project? If this **works**, you can check an older version of your own project and narrow down the problem. Which version of Unity do you use? Any differences between _Release_ and _Debug_ mode or _IL2CPP_ and _.NET_ as scripting backend? If a new empty project **refuses** to work: Are the credentials corrrect (different account)? Are you allowed to perform other tasks from device portal e.g. live view, delete files,.. ?

Comment: Unfortunately, due to time constraints we ran out of options and had to reset the device. I would encourage anyone else with this problem to try what you said above and deploy a new empty project. But resetting the device at least worked for us.